# Generic Meta and inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am generating python code using jinja templates from an XML file (FIBEX as defined in automotive). and would like to make the following classes generic:

```
from ctypes import *
import typing


def limits(c_int_type):
    signed = c_int_type(-1).value < c_int_type(0).value
    bit_size = sizeof(c_int_type) * 8
    signed_limit = 2 ** (bit_size - 1)
    return (-signed_limit, signed_limit - 1) if signed else (0, 2 * signed_limit - 1)


class MetaInt(type(c_uint8)):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        bit_size = dct['__getattr__'](None, 'bit_size')
        byte_size = dct['__getattr__'](None, 'byte_size')
        signed = dct['__getattr__'](None, 'signed')
        _min = dct['__getattr__'](None, 'min')
        _max = dct['__getattr__'](None, 'max')

        assert (1 <= bit_size <= byte_size * 8)
        assert (byte_size == sizeof(bases[0]))
        assert (signed == (bases[0](-1).value < bases[0](0).value))
        assert (limits(bases[0]) == (_min, _max))

        def __repr__(self):
            return str(bases[0].__name__) + '(' + str(self.value) + ')[' + name + ']'

        dct['__repr__'] = __repr__

        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)

#### This part would be generated and simply import the above class
class Foo(c_uint8, metaclass=MetaInt):

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == 'bit_size':
            return 6
        elif item == 'byte_size':
            return 1
        elif item == 'signed':
            return False
        elif item == 'min':
            return 0
        elif item == 'max':
            return 255
        elif str(item).startswith('__') and str(item).endswith('__'):
            return getattr(c_uint8(self), item)
        return getattr(item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'value':
            assert isinstance(value, int) and self.min <= value <= self.max
        setattr(key, value)


print(Foo(1))
```

The template looks like this:

```
from type_metas import {{type_meta}}

class Foo({{base_type}}, metaclass={{type_class}}):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'bit_size':
            return {{bit_size}}
        elif name == 'byte_size':
            return {{byte_size}}
        elif name == 'signed':
            return {{signed}}
        elif name == 'min':
            return {{min_val}}
        elif name == 'max':
            return {{max_val}}
        return getattr(name)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'value':
            assert isinstance(value, {{py_type}}) and self.min <= value <= self.max
        setattr(key, value)
```

---

---

### **Requirements**:

- **Current State**: Meta is not Generic, Each subclass need to be given an appropriate meta like `class Foo(c_uint8, metaclass=MetaUInt8):`
- **Desired State**: a Generic Metaclass like for instance this one which does not work:

Meta Attempt:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')
class MetaInt(typing.Generic[T], type(T)):
    ...
class Foo(typing.Generic[T], metaclass=MetaInt[T]):
    ...
print(Foo[c_uint8](1))
```

I got:

> TypeError: Cannot subclass special typing classes

I have tried a lot of things with no success.

---

---

**TLDR**: *A bit of context for those wondering what this is for*

The XML contains a definition of offered services by different ECU (Electronic Control Unit) speaking to each others in the car. (google "FIBEX xml")

Some signals will arrive in the same PDU (Protocol Data Unit), this XML tells me something like:

> Given the signal yyy from service xxx bits [6 to 10[ for the PDU (Bytes Big Endian, least significant bit) is a four bit signal that should be unpacked in ( and interpreted as ) an unsigned 8 bits integer. It will also have some extra property such has precision, Scaling (0 -> 0;255 -> 400km/h linearly), expected response delay, subscribable or not ... etc

A type in the end is just an interpretation of a packet of bytes. a+b where a and b are both 4 bytes packets should call completely different CPU instruction if these are floats, int or UTF8 chars... Also, even though int and uint will perform the same opcodes (2-complements arithmetic), they semantically mean something different.

But most types in a FIBEX have a C base datatype per the FIBEX.xsd schema.

```
<xs:attribute name="BASE-DATA-TYPE">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Specifying an ASAM harmonized data type. Use OTHER if none of them matches.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="A_UINT8"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_INT8"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_UINT16"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_INT16"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_UINT32"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_INT32"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_UINT64"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_INT64"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_FLOAT32"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_FLOAT64"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_ASCIISTRING"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_UNICODE2STRING"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_BYTEFIELD"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="A_BITFIELD"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="OTHER"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to reduce duplicate code (as in not having to type a new Meta class for each type), or are you trying to improve the type hints used by tools like mypy or your IDE ?

In general, the `typing` module is used for the latter. But I believe you are looking for the former.

In that case, I would try to use factory functions. Something like this:

```
def make_meta_int(_type):
    class MetaInt(type(_type)):
        def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
            ...
    return MetaInt

def make_foo(_type):
    class Foo(_type, metaclass=make_meta_int(_type)):

        def __getattr__(self, item):
            ...

            elif str(item).startswith('__') and str(item).endswith('__'):
                return getattr(_type(self), item)
            ...
        ...
    return Foo

Foo = make_foo(c_uint16)
print(Foo(1))
```

Comment: Indeed it works fine... I only need the make_meta_int factory. Then the class ``` Foo(c_uint8, metaclass=make_meta_int(c_uint8)) ``` is generated by jinja.

Unless someone else comes to answer how to do it with more classical generics, I will accept this answer.